# React Native MapBoxGL SimbolLayer shows on random position when zooming

Tags: javascript, react-native, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

I have a KML file from Google Earth that its gonna be converted to geojson. It contains 1 polygon and 2 point (marker).
However, when I load that geojson to ShapeSource like this code below

```
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map}>
        <MapboxGL.Camera
          zoomLevel={14}
          animationMode={'flyTo'}
          animationDuration={1100}
          centerCoordinate={[defaultMidPoint.longitude, defaultMidPoint.latitude]}
        />
        {mapsGeoJSON && (
          <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id={'shao'} shape={mapsGeoJSON}>
            <MapboxGL.FillLayer
              id={'previewArea'}
              style={{
                fillAntialias: true,
                fillColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                fillOutlineColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
              }}
            />

            <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
              id="marker"
              aboveLayerID="previewArea"
              style={{
                iconImage: division,
                iconSize: 1,
              }}
            />
          </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
        )}
      </MapboxGL.MapView>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

The props inside the geojson is loaded including the polygin and the marker. But the marker showing randomly on everywhere like this video. (please click on that giphy link)

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/8rcxy3ymU6y4wEbuly)

It should show 2 marker. How to achieve that?

My geojson:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              106.8338112502602,
              -6.201688127051138,
              16.87390009657168
            ],
            [
              106.8345784252153,
              -6.223435658941442,
              15.96151752351821
            ],
            [
              106.8499317207287,
              -6.223054276742122,
              14.95412051800844
            ],
            [
              106.8499303073782,
              -6.226010669074273,
              16.871529036928
            ],
            [
              106.8528087470502,
              -6.225819843794638,
              16.9254682421025
            ],
            [
              106.8526251591457,
              -6.203394339882926,
              8.018892591261013
            ],
            [
              106.8338112502602,
              -6.201688127051138,
              16.87390009657168
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Shape",
        "styleUrl": "#__managed_style_0ED941ED9221511A3486",
        "styleMapHash": {
          "normal": "#__managed_style_11DB66B07521511A3486",
          "highlight": "#__managed_style_2B474C71F521511A3486"
        }
      },
      "id": "067F9E7AC821511A3484"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          106.8375528929654,
          -6.219429389551594,
          0
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Placemark 1",
        "styleUrl": "#__managed_style_0ED941ED9221511A3486",
        "styleMapHash": {
          "normal": "#__managed_style_11DB66B07521511A3486",
          "highlight": "#__managed_style_2B474C71F521511A3486"
        }
      },
      "id": "06E2AC308B21511A76D1"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          106.8257462576387,
          -6.205879085150997,
          11.12209204998996
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Placemark 2",
        "styleUrl": "#__managed_style_0ED941ED9221511A3486",
        "styleMapHash": {
          "normal": "#__managed_style_11DB66B07521511A3486",
          "highlight": "#__managed_style_2B474C71F521511A3486"
        }
      },
      "id": "074354693A21511ACA82"
    }
  ]
}
```